# NoMethodError, undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass -rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I am getting NoMethodError in SitesController#index 
undefined method `subdomain' for nil:NilClass

I have an Accounts table that has a 'subdomain' field and a Site model which is a subclass of the Account Model that is:

```
class Site < Account

end

create_table "accounts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "subdomain"
  t.integer  "user_id"
```

end

and there is a current_account method defined in applications_controller like this

```
 def current_account
  if !is_root_domain?
   current_account = Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomains.first)
    if current_account.nil?
     redirect_to root_url(:account => false, :alert => "Unknown Account/subdomain")
  end
  else 
  current_account = nil
 end
return current_account
```

end

which calls is_root_domain? method below:

```
def is_root_domain?
  result = (request.subdomains.first.present? && request.subdomains.first != "www") ? false : true
```

end

I also chnaged the current_account method to this but got same error:

```
def current_account
    current_account = Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomains.first)
end
```

Under any of the above scenarios, i get the undefined method `subdomain' for nil:NilClass error on the SitesController#index. which is shown below while trying to access the url:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @site = Site.find_by_subdomain(current_account.subdomain)
  end

 def opps
   @site = Site.find_by_subdomain(current_account.subdomain)
 end
```

end

I have tried the various tricks of battling no method error that i know of, like adding 'attr_ccessible' and an initiliaze method but nothing seems to work. I also changed the Accounts table field from 'subdomain' to 'name', but no success. Any guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confused by the 'redirect_to' in ApplicationController#current_account.

This redirect doesn't happen immediately, it happens when everything else is finished.  So your current_account method will still return nil back to SitesController#index, where it is used to get the 'subdomain' and that's where you get your error.

If you call the redirect from a before_filter, it can handle this case before the code even enters your #index method.  I would restructure the code something like this.

```
class ApplicationController

  # get the current account from the subdomain, calling find only if first time..
  def current_account
    unless is_root_domain?
      @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomains.first)
    end
    @current_account
  end

end
```

And then:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_current_account

  def index
    @site = Site.find_by_subdomain(@current_account.subdomain)
  end

  private
  # makes sure @current_account is setup before using it elsewhere..
  def require_current_account
    if current_account.nil?
      redirect_to root_url(:account => false), :alert => "Unknown Account/subdomain"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: @bhouse thanks for your time, the nomethod error is gone so your code was really helpful. Dou you have any idea why it is spitting out the error message from redirect_to root_url as shown below:                                                                                                                 Started GET "/?alert=Unknown+Account%2Fsubdomain" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Mar 08 15
:54:05 +0000 2011
  Processing by SitesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"alert"=>"Unknown Account/subdomain"}
Redirected to http://lvh.me:3000/?alert=Unknown+Account%2Fsubdomain
Completed 302 Found in 0ms

Comment: @brg it's adding the alert as a query string because - if your code is as per the code above - you are passing it to the root_url method. Try change it to: `redirect_to root_url(:account => false), :alert => "Unknown Account/subdomain"`. As you can see, that add :account => false as a query string, which I assume is what you want, but passes the :alert to redirect_to.

Comment: @luke_randall, thanks i will change it now. Thanks for stopping and helping out.

Comment: @brg sorry, I just copied the redirect_to line without looking at it too closely.

Comment: @brg no problem @bhousel yeah, I figured as much :) +1 for a good answer though

Comment: Thanks @bhousel and luke_randall. The errors are gone. It now show redirected to http://lvh.me:300 which is the root domain but says completed 302 found and Firefox says that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. I am looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `current_account` is nil. Make sure you are setting the variable to a valid (existing) object instance.